# PostgreSQL: function to display columns in alphabetical order

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

On PostgreSQL, I need to see the table's columns in alphabetical order, so I'm using the query:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'organizations' ORDER BY column_name ASC;
```

I use it a lot every day, so I want to create a function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seecols(table_name text)
 RETURNS TABLE (column_name varchar, data_type varchar)
AS $func$
 DECLARE
 _query varchar;
 BEGIN
  -- Displays columns by alphabetic order
   _query := 'SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '''||table_name||''' ';

  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _query;
 END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I try:

```
SELECT seecols('organizations');
```

I'm getting:

```
 **structure of query does not match function result type**
```

I guess the line "RETURNS TABLE (column_name varchar, data_type varchar)" is wrongly defined. But since this is my first time using plpgsql, I don't know how to make it more dynamic.

Comment: Look at the data types for [information_schema.columns])https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html). They are not `varchar`. Probably easiest thing to do is : `SELECT column_name::varchar, data_type::varchar FROM  ...`. Otherwise: `RETURNS TABLE (column_name information_schema.sql_identifier, data_type information_schema.sql_identifier) `.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/infoschema-datatypes.html

Comment: Btw, no need for dynamic sql and building a string for the query. just use `RETURN SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column.table_name = seecols.table_name;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need neither dynamic sql nor plpgsql here. Just embed your sql query into a sql function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seecols (IN t_name text, OUT column_name varchar, OUT data_type varchar)
  RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE sql AS $$
  SELECT column_name, data_type 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = t_name 
   ORDER BY column_name ASC ;
$$ ;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0ho8WjXM)